Who was Governor of Monterey, California, before 1769?
I understand that Portolá's expedition of 1769 in Alta California was in part to re-establish contact with the successor of a Spanish 'governor' who had been left in Monterey some years (perhaps 80) before. There was no mission at Carmel then, and probably no trading post. A few Russian pelt-ships appear to have made it to Monterey before Portolá.
Does anyone have information about said 'governor(s)' and contact with Russian seafarers? So far I have found only glossing references.

Can you clarify, with quotes and citations, where you found that the reason for the Portola expedition was to 're-establish contact with the successor of a Spanish 'governor' who had been left in Monterey'. If we have the context of your source it might be easier to answer your question.
